# Initialize the default zoom

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, core-plot

**When my scatter plot appears, I see that :**

[image]

**But I would like to se that :**

[image]

Directly after chart loading, I want that the user see a chart with all data displaying, and not just a small piece like in the first screenshot. How can I define the original "zoom" ?

**EDIT : (here's my code)**

```
[...]
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

CPTScatterPlot *myPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
myPlot.dataSource = self;
myPlot.delegate = self;
CPTColor *myColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
[graph addPlot:myPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
myPlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 10.0f;

[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myPlot]];
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(DynamicValue)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(DynamicValue)];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the Core Plot example apps use `-[CPTPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:]` to adjust the plot ranges to the plot data. If you already know the data range, you set the plot space `xRange` and/or `yRange` directly when setting up the graph.

Comment: The data range is not always the same... And I'm already using the scaleToFitPlots: method. Please see the edit in my question.

Comment: What is `DynamicValue`? It should be greater than one (1). Also, make sure the plot data is available in the datasource when `scaleToFitPlots:` is called since that will force the plot to load its data to determine the range.

Comment: I set up a variable called dynamicValue which contains UISlider value for the user can adjust the range, because the amount of values is never the same, and sometimes the plot looks very "compressed"... So, thanks to these sliders (one for x axis, the other for y axis), the user can enlarge just one axis as he wants.

Comment: Oh, okay ! My problem was sometimes dynamicValue was less than 1... When I set a constant value like 1.5 for example, it works great. Thanks again Eric.

Comment: And is there a way to set the focus not on the plot, but on the axis ? My goal is to display, directly after the view's loading, a graph with the x-axis on the screen bottom, and the y-axis on the screen left side.

Comment: You can use `axisConstraints` to lock an axis to a certain position on the screen, e.g., a fixed distance from an edge or a percentage of the width or height.